# Is there a tool that let's you try big query for free

Tags: google-bigquery

If you are an individual in EU without a business you can't try it for free on google cloud platform.

Is there another tool out there that let's you try big query for free? Even something that can run locally and you just play around with small datasets.

Comment: I believe it is on topic as it is about a tool popular for programmers and it is practical and answerable. I don't want "a better tool" to attract opinionated answers.

Comment: The first terabyte of data that you query each month is free: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/

Comment: @ElliottBrossard thanks, but if you're from EU you cannot make an account without a business.

Comment: You just need a Google account. Like Elliot said, the first 1TB is free per month. I'm from the EU, and I have a personal Google account. I didn't need a _"business"_ to create it.

Comment: @GrahamPolley yes you need a business: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-use-Google-Cloud-Platform-as-individual-in-Europe I am now on the site, selecting a EU country and the only account available is business.

Comment: Wow. That must be a new restriction. So at what point are you getting caught out? When entering billing information? Do you already have a Google account? It would be great if you could add some more details and screenshots please...

Comment: Does this help (no credit card needed) - https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/01/how-to-run-a-terabyte-of-google-bigquery-queries-each-month-without-a-credit-card

Comment: @GrahamPolley awesome that works. I was clicking the try for free button and was getting only business accounts: https://snag.gy/BvOVua.jpg Thanks

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as an answer for people who may have the same problem in the future. If you could accept, that would be awesome ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 1 TB free per month with BigQuery, so there is nothing stopping you having a play with it. What's most likely catching you out is when you click "*Free Trial*" and you're asked to set up a billing account and enter a credit card etc. However, you don't need to do this.

You can use BigQuery (up to 1TB) **without** a credit card.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/01/how-to-run-a-terabyte-of-google-bigquery-queries-each-month-without-a-credit-card) for more details on how do to this. This will work for you.